# How to force position of a table?

Tags: tables, rotating

How to force position of a table using `sidewaystable` of `rotating` package?

My example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\textbf{The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black.}

%I need table here. 
\begin{sidewaystable}%I tried to use [H] and variations
    \centering
    \caption{Comparation between models with one regressor}
    \label{tab:eqm_regressor}
    \scalebox{.8}{
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{Scenario $C_1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_2$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_3$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_4$} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{PLR model} & CRM & PLR model & CRM & PLR model & CRM & PLR model & CRM\\ \hline
            $N$                  & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm sd$  & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$  \\ 
            \hline
            \multirow{1}{*}{3}   & $20.21 \pm 2.19$   & $100.35 \pm 3.73$    & $4.90 \pm 0.54$   & $81.75 \pm 2.20$ & $32.64 \pm 3.02$   & $233.71 \pm 12.50$ & $8.14 \pm 3.02$   & $231.98 \pm 12.50$ \\
            \multirow{1}{*}{4}   & $20.11 \pm 2.21$   & $105.26 \pm 3.86$   & $4.91 \pm 0.53$   & $85.93 \pm 2.43$ & $32.71 \pm 3.02$   & $247.62 \pm 12,82$ & $8.11 \pm 0.75$   & $245,78 \pm 11,88$\\
            \multirow{1}{*}{6}   & $20.07 \pm 2.25$   & $105.00 \pm 3.82$   & $4.87 \pm 0.56$   & $85.93 \pm 2.40$ & $32.71 \pm 3.05$   & $247.51 \pm 12.72$ & $8.15 \pm 0.77$   & $246.01 \pm 11.56$\\
            \multirow{1}{*}{100} & $20.07 \pm 2.23$   & $104.88 \pm 3.77$   & $4.91 \pm 0.54$   & $86,03 \pm 2.30$ & $32,62 \pm 2,95$   & $247.96 \pm 12.92$ & $8.18 \pm 0.73$   & $245.20 \pm 12.07$\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}%
\end{sidewaystable}

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post compilable code, not just fragments. Which position should be forced?

Comment: I fully agree with the information of my dear colleague Christian.

Comment: A `tabular` will always go exactly where you place it. The only reason for using a `table` (or `sidewaystable`) environment is to allow latex to move it to help with page breaking.

Comment: I completed the question.

Comment: Aside: Not one of the `\multirow` directives is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torbjorn has already provided an answer to show to use a `\clearpage` statement to achieve your layout objectives.

I'd like to suggest that rather than use the `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` "hammers" to make the width of the (rotated) textblock, you should look into making judicious spacing adjustments by hand. You'll get a far more readable table that way. The screenshot shows the proposed solution above your code's solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out column spacing
\caption{Proposed new look}
\label{tab:eqm_regressor}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l*{8}{C} }
\toprule
$N$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_1$} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_2$} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_3$} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_4$} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
& \mbox{PLR model} & \mbox{CRM} & \mbox{PLR model} & \mbox{CRM} 
& \mbox{PLR model} & \mbox{CRM} & \mbox{PLR model} & CRM\\ 
\addlinespace
& \overline{MSE} {\pm} dp & \overline{MSE} {\pm} sd 
& \overline{MSE} {\pm} dp & \overline{MSE} {\pm} dp 
& \overline{MSE} {\pm} dp & \overline{MSE} {\pm} dp 
& \overline{MSE} {\pm} dp & \overline{MSE} {\pm} dp \\ 
\midrule
3  & 20.21 {\pm} 2.19 & 100.35 {\pm} 3.73 
   &  4.90 {\pm} 0.54 &  81.75 {\pm} 2.20 
   & 32.64 {\pm} 3.02 & 233.71 {\pm} 12.50 
   &  8.14 {\pm} 3.02 & 231.98 {\pm} 12.50 \\
4  & 20.11 {\pm} 2.21 & 105.26 {\pm} 3.86 
   &  4.91 {\pm} 0.53 &  85.93 {\pm} 2.43 
   & 32.71 {\pm} 3.02 & 247.62 {\pm} 12.82 
   &  8.11 {\pm} 0.75 & 245.78 {\pm} 11.88\\
6  & 20.07 {\pm} 2.25 & 105.00 {\pm} 3.82 
   &  4.87 {\pm} 0.56 &  85.93 {\pm} 2.40 
   & 32.71 {\pm} 3.05 & 247.51 {\pm} 12.72 
   &  8.15 {\pm} 0.77 & 246.01 {\pm} 11.56\\
100& 20.07 {\pm} 2.23 & 104.88 {\pm} 3.77 
   &  4.91 {\pm} 0.54 &  86.03 {\pm} 2.30 
   & 32.62 {\pm} 2.95 & 247.96 {\pm} 12.92 
   &  8.18 {\pm} 0.73 & 245.20 {\pm} 12.07\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\caption{Original Look}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt} % restore default value
\centering
\scalebox{.8}{
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{Scenario $C_1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_2$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_3$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_4$} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{PLR model} & CRM & PLR model & CRM & PLR model & CRM & PLR model & CRM\\ \hline
            $N$                  & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm sd$  & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$  \\ 
            \hline
            \multirow{1}{*}{3}   & $20.21 \pm 2.19$   & $100.35 \pm 3.73$    & $4.90 \pm 0.54$   & $81.75 \pm 2.20$ & $32.64 \pm 3.02$   & $233.71 \pm 12.50$ & $8.14 \pm 3.02$   & $231.98 \pm 12.50$ \\
            \multirow{1}{*}{4}   & $20.11 \pm 2.21$   & $105.26 \pm 3.86$   & $4.91 \pm 0.53$   & $85.93 \pm 2.43$ & $32.71 \pm 3.02$   & $247.62 \pm 12,82$ & $8.11 \pm 0.75$   & $245,78 \pm 11,88$\\
            \multirow{1}{*}{6}   & $20.07 \pm 2.25$   & $105.00 \pm 3.82$   & $4.87 \pm 0.56$   & $85.93 \pm 2.40$ & $32.71 \pm 3.05$   & $247.51 \pm 12.72$ & $8.15 \pm 0.77$   & $246.01 \pm 11.56$\\
            \multirow{1}{*}{100} & $20.07 \pm 2.23$   & $104.88 \pm 3.77$   & $4.91 \pm 0.54$   & $86,03 \pm 2.30$ & $32,62 \pm 2,95$   & $247.96 \pm 12.92$ & $8.18 \pm 0.73$   & $245.20 \pm 12.07$\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}%
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `\clearpage` right after the `sidewaystable`. This does of course give you a very bad pagebreak before the table.

Below I also edited the table a bit, using the rules from the `booktabs` package, and added an empty cell at the start of the first two header rows, so that you don't have the first `Scenario` and `PLR model` spanning the `N` column as well.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \cmidrule, \bottomrule   

\begin{document}

\textbf{The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black. The house is black.}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{Comparation between models with one regressor}
    \label{tab:eqm_regressor}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_2$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_3$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scenario $C_4$} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
            & PLR model & CRM & PLR model & CRM & PLR model & CRM & PLR model & CRM\\ \midrule
            $N$                  & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm sd$  & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$ & $\overline{MSE} \pm dp$  \\ 
            \midrule
            3   & $20.21 \pm 2.19$   & $100.35 \pm 3.73$    & $4.90 \pm 0.54$   & $81.75 \pm 2.20$ & $32.64 \pm 3.02$   & $233.71 \pm 12.50$ & $8.14 \pm 3.02$   & $231.98 \pm 12.50$ \\
            4   & $20.11 \pm 2.21$   & $105.26 \pm 3.86$   & $4.91 \pm 0.53$   & $85.93 \pm 2.43$ & $32.71 \pm 3.02$   & $247.62 \pm 12,82$ & $8.11 \pm 0.75$   & $245,78 \pm 11,88$\\
            6   & $20.07 \pm 2.25$   & $105.00 \pm 3.82$   & $4.87 \pm 0.56$   & $85.93 \pm 2.40$ & $32.71 \pm 3.05$   & $247.51 \pm 12.72$ & $8.15 \pm 0.77$   & $246.01 \pm 11.56$\\
            100 & $20.07 \pm 2.23$   & $104.88 \pm 3.77$   & $4.91 \pm 0.54$   & $86,03 \pm 2.30$ & $32,62 \pm 2,95$   & $247.96 \pm 12.92$ & $8.18 \pm 0.73$   & $245.20 \pm 12.07$\\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}%
\end{sidewaystable}
\clearpage% added

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the tabular's width is set to `\textwidth`, the `\centering` instruction is not needed.

Comment: @Mico Good point, thanks. (And I fully agree with your advice to not use `scalebox`/`resizebox` by the way, I guess I was a bit lazy when I answered yesterday.)